# JQuery datatable refreshing after Serverside processing

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have one table having number of columns in which some columns are dependent on the other.

How can I refresh the jQuery datatable after editing one column in the table so that values at other columns are also updated after server side processing.

Comment: Send a request to the server and render the response.

Comment: that is not working, it is only updating the column which i have edited not the other fields which are dependent on the column which i have edited

Comment: Then send a request to the server which returns all updated values and render the response. Without example code, it is impossible to give more than a general answer. You can [edit] your question to include additional details and example code, which shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this approach, but I've seen that everything in datatables is done through  custom functions. For example, in the buttons section, you can add a custom button with

```
        ,{
    "sExtends":    "text",
    "sButtonText": "Refressh Serverside",
    "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
                             MyRefreshFn();
        }
    }
```

where MyRefreshFn(); can be anything you want. You can define it outside the datatables declaration and use, for example, jQuery.ajax to detect when the server answers, then trigger a common Datatables method. In your case, you might want to trigger the whole row rendering queue, to make the changed value affect every other dependant cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, after getting response refresh page. If you are using some plugin find his documentation you will get method related to refresh.

OR send request to same page and display it. It gives you fresh result.

```
$.post("page_url",{parameter},function(data, textStatus,req){
 $("div_id").html(req.responseText);
});
```